# Замена заголовка и картинки формы в зависимости по какой кнопке был сделан клик

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 4 `div` с кнопками. По клику на кнопку открывается модальное окно, которое должно брать заголовок и картинку из `div`'a. Как осуществить такую магию?

```js
$('.izdat_button').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('.izdat p').html();
  var imgMe = $('.izdat img').attr('src');

  $('.time_to_change').html(value);
  $('.img_izdat img').attr('src', imgMe);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"1"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/2.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"2"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/3.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"3"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/4.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"4"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>



<div style="display: none;">
  <div class="box-modal" id="instructions_form">
    <div class="wrap_form">
      <p class="time_to_change">Инструкция<br><strong>1</strong></p>
      <div class="img_izdat">
        <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), для того чтобы найти соседние элементы с той кнопкой, на которую нажали.

Сейчас же в вашем коде нет уточнения, и возвращается первый найденный `.izdat p` и `.izdat img`

```js
$('.izdat_button').on('click', function(e) {
  var value = $(this).siblings('.izdat p').html();
  var imgMe = $(this).siblings('.izdat img').attr('src');
  console.log(value);
  $('.time_to_change').html(value);
  $('.img_izdat img').attr('src', imgMe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция1<br><strong>"1"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/2.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция2<br><strong>"2"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>

<hr> modal:
<div>
  <div class="box-modal" id="instructions_form">
    <div class="wrap_form">
      <p class="time_to_change">Инструкция<br><strong>1</strong></p>
      <div class="img_izdat">
        <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы "взять" необходимые `html` и `img` в блоке, в котором была нажата кнопка, для начала можно определить этот самый блок, используя, например, метод [.closest()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA), а уже в нем искать необходимый вам элементы:

```js
$('.izdat_button').on('click', function() {
  var izdat = $(this).closest('.izdat'); // блок .izdat, в котором нажата кнопка
  var value = izdat.find('p').html();
  var imgMe = izdat.find('img').attr('src');

  $('.time_to_change').html(value);
  $('.img_izdat img').attr('src', imgMe);

  console.log('HTML: ' + value + ', SRC: ' + imgMe); // для демонстрации
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"1"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/2.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"2"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/3.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"3"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>
<div class="izdat">
  <img src="img/4.png" alt="">
  <p>Инструкция<br><strong>"4"</strong></p>
  <button class="izdat_button" type="submit">Подробнее</button>
</div>


<div class="box-modal" id="instructions_form">
  <div class="wrap_form">
    <p class="time_to_change">Инструкция<br><strong>1</strong></p>
    <div class="img_izdat">
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```